What is the non deprecated way of setting the transaction manager into the listener container is spring kafka 3.2?
I am using sprking kafka and noticed in version 3.2 the setTransactionManager has been deprecated in ContainerProperties:
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, PersonDto> inContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, PersonDto> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(inConsumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(kafkaTransactionManager);
    return factory;
}

The problem is it doesn't say what to use instead in order to wire the transaction manager into the listener container ( I cannot use spring boot's configuration only in .yml since I need to configure multiple listener container, some transactional and some not ).
How can I set the transaction manager in spring kafka 3.2 the right way?

That method is deprecated in favor of:
/**
 * Set the transaction manager to start a transaction; replace {@link #setTransactionManager}.
 * @param kafkaAwareTransactionManager the transaction manager.
 * @since 3.2
 */
public void setKafkaAwareTransactionManager(@Nullable KafkaAwareTransactionManager<?, ?> kafkaAwareTransactionManager) {

The change has been done here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/3066
And it is mentioned in the What's New chapter of that Spring for Apache Kafka 3.2: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/whats-new.html#x32-cp-ptm

In Spring Kafka 3.2, you can use the setTransactionManager() method directly on the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.
Here's the corrected approach:
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties.AckMode;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer2;

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, PersonDto> inContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, PersonDto> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(inConsumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE); // Example AckMode
    factory.setTransactionManager(kafkaTransactionManager()); // Set Transaction Manager
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTransactionManager<Long, PersonDto> kafkaTransactionManager() {
    return new KafkaTransactionManager<>(producerFactory());
}

This should address the deprecation warning you encountered, as setTransactionManager() on ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory is the correct replacement.

Thanks for responding Vedant. This is what I am doing also but the metod setTransactionManager has been deprected         factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(transactionManager)). My question is what to use instead of that method?
